# Barcode Font Won't Work Properly On Other Devices CrystalReports C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[image]I'm developing a software to print barcode lables using CrystalReports and c#, for the code I used a dataset with 4 fields, one for the barcode, one for the product name, one for the price and the last one for the number of labels, then I designed the report and I passed the data from the dataset. Every thing works perfectly on my machine, in other machines however, every thing looks good except that the barcode font doesn't work!!!

The font that I'm using: IDAutomationHC39M (Free Edition)

Comment: It maybe your scanner is more forgiving, is the barcode big enough?

Comment: HoneyWell Orbit, But the problem has nothing to do with the scanner brother, the font itself isn't working when I preview the crystal report

Comment: Then then Fenton is correct it would imply that the other machines dont have the font installed. Check the font shows up in some app like wordpad, or such

Comment: What do you mean with 'the barcode font doesn't work'? Is not not printed / not printed correctly or is it not scannable? Please double check if there is a rtl/ltr issue - i can't tell with your provided test data '1001' ;)

Comment: The image here is on my machine, on other machines only the data '1001' appear the bars don't appear... got it bro? @nilsK

Comment: I installed it on other machines @BugFinder

Comment: Did you check another app to see if it picks up the font? it seems odd it doesnt pick it up if it got installed

Comment: @BugFinder Yup... MS Word... I designed a table and I placed some text, then I changed the font of the text to the specific front (IDAutomationHC39M) and it worked like a charm, it seems crazy

Comment: have you rebooted the machine? some services may not have picked up the change in font and if you're using things like print to PDF.... I saw something similar with SQL reports

Comment: @BugFinder Actually not... I will try that.. the whole thing is driving me crazy... the font is already installed.. and it's working on other apps... could it be somethi g wrong in the code?

Comment: We had a team here with similar barcode issues much swearing was had, turned out they used 3 different barcode fonts (why???) and under SQL reports the barcode showed, but wouldnt print until you rebooted the machine

Comment: @BugFinder Ahaaa. I will try it then... thanks for your patience with me brother... I will report to you soon.... thanks again 

Comment: (cough, Im not male)

Comment: @BugFinder  I'm truly sorry sister... my bad

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the font on the server. You probably already installed it locally (i.e. you dragged it into the font folder, or right-clicked and selected "Install Font").

The font needs to be on the machine the report runs on.

Comment: I already did that, I installed the font on every device that I used to try the software